# glMultiDrawElementsIndirect custom drawID with multiple instances per DrawElementsIndirectCommand

Tags: opengl

If I setup a custom ascending integer drawID vertex buffer stream for per instance data with:

```
glVertexAttribDivisor(drawIDVertexStreamIdx, 1)
```

Using glMultiDrawElementsIndirect() given:

```
struct DrawElementsIndirectCommand
{
    uint  count;
    uint  instanceCount;
    uint  firstIndex;
    uint  baseVertex;
    uint  baseInstance;
};
```

When setting the instanceCount to more than one, I am confused looking at old notes and online about what exactly happens regards the drawID passed to the shader?

If say there are two DrawElementsIndirectCommand records invoked from one glMultiDrawElementsIndirect(), with the first record having an instanceCount of 3, and the second an instanceCount of say 1, what do the instances actually see in the shader?  (Assuming the drawID vertex stream contains 0,1,2,3 etc)

Are they supposed to see 0,1,2 for the first DrawElementsIndirectCommand record instances, and 3 for the second DrawElementsIndirectCommand record instance?

All the examples I can find online seem to specifically set instanceCount to one and rely on multiple DrawElementsIndirectCommand records which makes me now doubt this understanding is correct?

```
const int CustomDrawIDIdx = 1;
const int VertexCount = 4;
DrawElementsIndirectCommand drawCallRecords[2] =
{
    { VertexCount, 3, 0, 0, 0 },
    { VertexCount, 1, 0, 0, 0 },
};

...
//  Attempt to set up custom drawID from a vertex attribute, where the vertex stream for it is a sequence of integers 0, 1, 2 etc
glVertexAttribIPointer(CustomDrawIDIdx, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, NULL);
glVertexAttribDivisor(CustomDrawIDIdx, 1);
...

glMultiDrawElementsIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &drawCallRecords, 2, 0);
```

In the vertex shader:

```
layout (location = 1) in uint customDrawID;

void main()
{
    bool match = (customDrawID== gl_InstanceID); 
    ...
}
```

So this should cause 4 actual draw calls, as actual draw calls caused by glMultiDrawElementsIndirect() are determined by the number DrawElementsIndirectCommand records and their contained instance counts.

For each draw call gl_InstanceID should start from zero and count up for each instance, but go back to zero after each DrawElementsIndirectCommand record is processed?

So gl_InstanceID should do (0, 1, 2) for drawCallRecords[0], and then (0) for drawCallRecords[1]? What does the customDrawID do?

I am also curious if ARB_shader_draw_parameters on nVidia (GTX1070+) is still not recommended compared to using a custom drawID from a vertex stream?

*** UPDATE to reflect the answer by the very patient and helpful Nicol Bolas:

So given:

```
DrawElementsIndirectCommand drawCallRecords[2] =
{
    { VertexCount, 3, 0, 0, 0 },
    { VertexCount, 1, 0, 0, 3 /*baseInstance will push us along in customDrawID vertex stream*/ },
};
```

Then customDrawID will then do (0, 1, 2) and (3) across all instances in the multidrawindirect.

Which means that each drawn instance across the TWO draw calls, and the 3 + 1 total instances drawn (3 instances of one 'object', 1 instance of another 'object'), in one multidrawindirect call could reference completely unique transformation matrices for example.  And in essence that emulates the functionality of gl_DrawID as long as you keep bumping the baseInstance like that (exclusive sum style) for each DrawElementsIndirectCommand record.

The baseInstance in each DrawElementsIndirectCommand record will push the offset into the customDrawID vertex stream, giving a customDrawID that is unique to each instance across all objects drawn.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "a custom drawID"? Are you talking about the value of `gl_DrawID` or the value of something else?

Comment: By custom drawID I mean a value sourced from a vertex buffer stream not the built in gl_DrawID: http://www.openglsuperbible.com/2013/10/16/the-road-to-one-million-draws/

Comment: Another example is: https://www.g-truc.net/post-0518.html

Comment: And slides 31-33: https://www.slideshare.net/CassEveritt/approaching-zero-driver-overhead

Comment: I don't see where any of those sources say that shader_draw_parameters is "not recommended" for this purpose.

Comment: On slide 33 of the the AZDO it mentions it not being optimal for some GPUs, I've also seen it mentioned elsewhere and in developer conversations - I believe it was AMD that had no problem with it, but that it was slower on nvidia - I am not sure if post nvidia pascal if that's no longer an issue now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So this should cause 4 actual draw calls, as actual draw calls caused by glMultiDrawElementsIndirect() are determined by the number DrawElementsIndirectCommand records and their contained instance counts.

No. Instances and "draw calls" are not the same thing.

A single draw call is defined as if by a call to `glDraw*InstancedBaseVertexBaseInstance`; that's what happens when the system reads a single entry from the array of draw data. That single draw call includes *all instances*. Instancing is a thing that happens within a draw call.

This is also why per-instance values are not guaranteed to be [dynamically uniform expressions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Dynamically_Uniform_Expression).

Individual draws within a multi-draw command are, `gl_DrawID` aside, completely *separate* from one another. They do not interact. The values your shader gets for instanced arrays or `gl_InstanceID` would be no different from issuing each draw call separately.

Your "custom drawID" is not a draw ID at all; it is an instanced array value. Therefore, it follows the rules of instancing, and cares *nothing* for which draw call it is in.

---

> ```
> bool match = (customDrawID== gl_InstanceID);
> ```

No.

Even if the actual array you use to feed `customDrawID` is just a zero-based integer index, instances arrays and `gl_InstanceID` don't work the same way.

`gl_InstanceID` ignores the base instance. Instance arrays *do not*. As such, the instance value fetched from any instance array will always be offset first by the base instance.

So if you want the `customDrawID` for a specific draw call to start from a particular value, then you set `baseInstance` to be the instance index of that particular value. So given a zero-based integer index array, if you want a particular draw call to have its first instance receive the `customDrawID` value of "3", you set `baseInstance` to 3.

Comment: It's specifically the behaviour of a 'custom drawID' sourced from a vertex buffer stream/attribute (where the vertex buffer is a list of sequential integers) that I am interested in (so I can actually profile it against gl_DrawID correctly).

Comment: @iam: That only affects how you *use* my answer. Your "custom drawID" is not a draw ID; it's just an instanced value, and therefore acts in accord with the rules of *instancing*. Which I state in the first and last paragraphs.

Comment: Sorry this isn't clear to me still.  With "instances all happen within a draw call" does that mean one DrawElementsIndirectCommand record is a draw call or all DrawElementsIndirectCommand records issued from one glMultiDrawElementsIndirect() are counted as one draw call from the instancing point of view?  In the former case I would then expect to see (0, 0, 0) and (0) as the custom drawID in the example I state in the question, in the latter I would expect (0, 1, 2) and (3).

Comment: Or actually are you saying I would see (0, 1, 2) and (0).  And that without using the real gl_drawID there is no way to differentiate between the DrawElementsIndirectCommand records?

Comment: @iam: What you call "records" in your multidraw command are more correctly called "draw calls". Because that's what they are: indirect rendering is defined exactly as if the implementation read the data structure and made a call to `glDraw*InstancedBaseVertexBaseInstance` with the parameters read from the data structure. A multi-draw-indirect call is just doing that more than once. But each draw's parameters are *completely independent* of any other draw's parameters.

Comment: Ah ok that helps, so that would mean that I would expect to see (0, 1, 2) and (0).  And that without the real gl_DrawID there is indeed no way of knowing which DrawElementsIndirectCommand record (draw call) is happening (hence why the examples I could find only used an instanceCount of 1).  I think it would help prevent other people from being as confused if the answer was updated to reflect this.

Comment: @iam: "*And that without the real gl_DrawID there is indeed no way of knowing which DrawElementsIndirectCommand record (draw call) is happening (hence why the examples I could find only used an instanceCount of 1).*" You're assuming something I never said. I only stated how what you described would play out. That doesn't mean you can't achieve the effect you want. It just doesn't happen *by itself*. Consider the effect of the last parameter in your "record", for example.

Comment: In the case of not using ARB_shader_draw_parameters though the shader cannot get access to the baseInstance member though right?  So for example without ARB_shader_draw_parameters if I wanted to issue a glMultiDrawElementsIndirect() as stated in the example in the question and get (0, 1, 2, 3) and (4) in the shader for indexing say into a per object transform (5 objects in total, one glMultiDrawElementsIndirect call, with 2 DrawElementsIndirectCommand records passed).

Comment: "*the shader cannot get access to the baseInstance member though right?*" But you're not using `gl_InstanceID`, are you? You should remind yourself of how the rules work for [base instance rendering.](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Instanced_Rendering) Specifically, what is and is not affected by the base instance.

Comment: Oops in my earlier comment I meant (0, 1, 2) and (3), not (0, 1, 2, 3) and (4).  I'm now verging on being completely confused though.  gl_InstanceID in my example in the question should give (0, 1, 2) and (0) right?  Which would be the same as the 'custom drawID from vertex stream' anyway?  That gl_InstanceID in vertex shaders is stated not to be effected by the baseInstance is why I said the shader cannot get access to that regards your comment on the "last parameter of a record".

Comment: I've updated to the question to maybe make it more helpful.

Comment: @iam: If everything you say is true... what *does* `baseInstance` affect? If it doesn't affect `gl_InstanceID`, and it doesn't affect the value fetched from an instanced array (aka: what your "custom drawID" really is), why does it exist?

Comment: From: khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing it says "The input gl_InstanceID does not follow the baseinstance​. gl_InstanceID always falls on the half-open range [0, instancecount​ ). So the base instance is only useful when using Instanced Arrays. With OpenGL 4.6 or ARB_shader_draw_parameters, you have access to gl_BaseInstance, which is the baseinstance​ value used in the rendering command".  From: khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Instanced_arrays, it appears baseInstance affects the offset for the vertex attribute stream?  I am unsure how that relates to multidraw.

Comment: I've updated the end of my question to reflect your answer? As maybe I get it now finally?  If so thank you, and I can accept your answer.  If not then I shall hang my head in shame lol.

Comment: Also I believe your note regards dynamically uniform is to warn against trying to use the custom draw ID to index into a UBO array of object transforms for example, as this would require the use of SSBO, unless gl_DrawID was actually used instead.